# Itô integral and stock prices in discrete time.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $X_n\sim \text{Bernoulli}(\frac{1}{2})$ with state space $\{-1,1\}$ i.i.d for all $n$. Set $S_n=X_0+X_1+...+X_n$.

Suppose that $X_0=2$ a.s. then $\{S_n\}$ has independent increment  $\text{Bernoulli}(p,n)$.

I know that $$\int_0^3S_ndS_n=S_0(S_1-S_0)+S_1(S_2-S_1)+S_2(S_3-S_2).$$

Financially speaking, $S_n$ is the quantity of asset at time $n$ or at time $n+1$ ? I'm a bit confuse...

### **My attempts**

Let $n$ denote the days.

- At $n=0$ I buy $X_0=2$ assets that have price $S_0$. Now, suppose that the price change at midnight and until midnight I can't buy or sale any asset.
- At $n=1$ at midnight the price of the asset is now $S_1$. So, I have now $S_0$ asset at $S_1$ dollars. My profit is therefore $$S_1S_0-S_0S_0=S_0(S_1-S_0)=\int_0^1 S_ndS_n,$$
- Now I buy $X_1$ asset at price $S_1$, and thus you have $S_0+X_1=S_1$ assets that have price $S_1$ dollars. I can't buy nor sale any asset until midnight.
- At $n=2$ at midnight, the price of the assets is now $S_2$, and thus, I have $S_1$ assets at $S_2$ dollars. Therefore, my profit since the day $1$ is $$-X_1S_1+S_2S_1.$$

**Question :** But it should be $$-S_1S_1+S_2S_1=(S_2-S_1)S_1=\int_1^2 S_ndS_n,$$
but I really don't understand how to get that.

At the very end I get $$-S_0S_0+S_0S_1-X_1S_1+S_2S_1$$
instead of $$S_0S_0+S_0S_1-S_1S_1+S_2S_1,$$
and I really don't understand how to get this previous formula. Could someone help ?

Comment: Why are you considering the integral $\int S_n dS_n$? In my opinion, it would make more sense to consider something like $\int_0^k H_n dS_n$, where $(H_n)$ is the amount of assets held from time $n-1$ to $n$ (a trading strategy). Then the integral would be the profit/loss up to time $k$ from trading with this trading strategy.

Comment: @TkiDeneb: It's my exercise, not me ;) It's to see how $\int B_tdB_t$ works...

Comment: It sounds like the modeling situation that you're considering is that $S_n$ is the price of the asset after its price has changed $n$ times. $\int S_n dS_n$ with Bernoulli increments is then a process which steps up by $S_n$ whenever $X_{n+1}=1$ and otherwise sits where it is.

Comment: (Cont.) Why would it step up by $S_n$? That's going to depend on other inputs to the problem; one way for that to happen would be to buy another copy of the asset each time the price rises, in which case $\int S_n dS_n$ will be the difference between the value of the portfolio and the total amount you paid for it (assuming that you only make purchases immediately after the price rises, so that purchases are never instantaneously profitable).

Comment: Then you can just take $H_n = S_n$.  (I made a mistake above: $H_n$ should be the amount of assets held from time $n$ to time $n+1$.)  So in this case you buy $H_0 = S_0$ assets at time $0$ and hold them untill time $1$, yielding a profit of $S_0(S_1-S_0)$. Then you buy/sell $S_1 - S_0$ assets, so you now have $S_1$. (The profit/loss from this transaction is not reflected in the integral.) Then you hold these $S_1$ assets from time $1$ to time $2$, yielding a profit/loss of $S_1(S_2-S_1)$. Etc. Again, the integral doesn't include the profit/loss from rebuying/reselling inbetween timesteps.

Comment: What do you mean by "buy/sell" ? If I have $S_0$ asset, I just have to buy $X_1$ other asset, no ? @TkiDeneb

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure to totally understand what you mean... This model is not working ? Why ?

Comment: Yes, since $X_1 = S_1 - S_0$. I wrote buy/sell because the sign of $X_1$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: @TkiDeneb: Ok, but I still have the problem that $S_0S_0+S_0S_1−X_1S_1+S_2S_1$ for the integral instead of $S_0S0+S_0S_1−S_1S_1+S_2S_1$, so it doesn't work...

Comment: The profit from day one is $S_1(S_2 - S_1)$. Like I said, the integral doesn't include profit/loss from trading inbetween the timesteps.

Comment: @TkiDeneb: I'm a bit new in stochastic calculs. So as I could read in your comment, stochastic integral is just the gain, and there is a difference with gain an profit ? (for me they both mean the same, but apparently you make distinction). So if you bet $2$ dollars and gain 3 times the bet, the gain (i.e. stochastic integral) is $6$, and the profit is $4$ ? Or, if I bet 2 dollars, and get 3 times the bet and then bet 1 dollars and win 3 times the bet, the gain (i.e. the stochastic integral) is $9$ and the profit is $6$. Is this right ?

Comment: Look what I wrote above. The (discrete) stochastic integral gives the profit/loss obtained during the time periods, for example $S_0 (S_1 - S_0) + S_1 (S_2-S_1)$ for holding $S_0$ shares from time $0$ to $1$ and $S_1$ shares from time $1$ to $2$. It does not include the money we have to put in or take out to go from $S_0$ to $S_1$ shares at time $1$.

Answer (score 1):

$S_n$ is the value of the asset on day $n$. On day $0$, the asset has value $S_0=2$. That midnight, the price changes by $X_1$ to $S_0+X_1=S_1$, so $S_1$ is the price on day $1$.

Since we are doing $\int_0^n S_n\,dS_n$, we are also assuming that $S_n$ is the amount of the asset you own after buying shares on day $n$. You start by buying $S_0=2$ units on day $0$, then during the day on day $1$ you buy $X_1$ shares, so you own $S_0+X_1=S_1$ of the asset.

---

After buying $X_1$ assets on day $1$, you have $S_0+X_1=S_1$ assets at price $S_1$.

On day $2$, after the price change at midnight, you have $S_1$ assets at price $S_2$.

Therefore, your overnight profit is
$$
-S_1\times S_1+S_1\times S_2=S_1(S_2-S_1).
$$